# Why is that "therefore" is usually followed by a comma and not "and so"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, conjunctions

I thought "therefore" and "and so" meant basically the same. Why, then, is "therefore" usually [followed by a comma](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=%22therefore%22&l=0#q=therefore%20%2Fr%3As&findid=-1&ff=&ffo=true&l=0&t=0)? (When it appears at the beginning of a sentence.)

> Therefore, Sunday's Super Bowl could be the last game played this
>   calendar year.

And not [and so](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?hardm=1&t=0&l=0&p=1&q=%22and%20so%22%20%2Fr%3As)?

> And so they've shown more than 10 years of strong, solid, consistent growth now.

Is there are grammatical, practical, or logical reason?

Answer (score 1):

A comma can be used to separate clauses in the same sentence. It doesn't *always* go after the word "therefore". One of the most famous quotes containing the word is:

> I think, therefore I am.

"Therefore" is a conjunctive adverb that you can use as a transition word in sentences and paragraphs. In your example, it begins a sentence, so there must have been a sentence before it that relates to it. The comma is there to show that you have made a transition between two linked clauses. For example:

> John was born in England. Therefore, John is British.

This could also be written with a semicolon:

> John was born in England; therefore, John is British.

"So" is different from "therefore" as it can be a conjunction or a basic adverb, whereas "therefore" can only be a conjunction. "So" is far less formal than "therefore". You can use "so" to join things that naturally followed one another, whereas "therefore" introduces logical conclusions proved by the previous statement.

For example:

> We planned to go to the zoo but it rained so we went somewhere else.

Going somewhere else was not a logical conclusion based on the information that preceded it. It was just the thing that followed. They *could* have gone to the zoo in the rain! So really there is no need for a comma to break up this train of thought into separate clauses.

Comment: How about "and so"? I think "and so" acts as "therefore," but most people don't put a comma after it.

Comment: @alexchenco I've appended my answer.